# Wildfly: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:4.2}server'

Tags: jboss, wildfly, undertow

Error:

```
17:42:50,333 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 10.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) starting
17:42:50,732 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0055: Caught exception during boot: org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationPersistenceException: WFLYCTL0085: Failed to parse configuration
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:131)
    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:356)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:299)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:4.2}server'
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.processNested(XMLMapperImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.staxmapper.XMLMapperImpl.parseDocument(XMLMapperImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.XmlConfigurationPersister.load(XmlConfigurationPersister.java:123)
    ... 3 more

17:42:50,733 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

I'm getting this error from the beginning of my standalone-full.xml. I've used an xml validator on the file and its syntax is correct.  I assume it's a problem with my environment.

Comment: for me, I was using Jboss EAP 6.4. Switched to EAP 7.0 and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

The 4.2 version of the `server` URN is for WildFly 10.1.0.Final. It looks like you're using WildFly 10.0.0.Final. You'd need to use version 4.0 of the URN or upgrade your WildFly server to 10.1.0.Final.

Comment: Yes true, totally true. ThumbsUP

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1]
>   Message: Unexpected element '{urn:jboss:domain:4.2}server'

Remove `server` from `{urn:jboss:domain:4.2}server`  line number 2 in `standalone-full.xml` and try to start server.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this error message with WildFly 26.1.2. The standalone-full.xml was fine, the problem was with my modules.

I had a bug with my Docker image, that deploys WildFly locally. A step in the Dockerfile copies a tar.gz file with our custom modules. Since I was in the process of upgrading from WildFly 10.1.0 to 26.1.2, an old zip with old modules was added to the modules folder.

I have no clue why this happens, but removing old modules.tar.gz did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check your standalone.xml which you are using as configuration for your Jboss.

In the beginning of standalone.xml and standalone-full.xml look out for

```
<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:x.y">
```

make sure the x.y matches to the server URN for the version of wildfly you are using.